# debugging an ssis package which is invoked from a .net application?

Tags: sql-server-2008, business-intelligence, debugging

can we attach a debugger to an SSIS package which is invoked to execute from a .net assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSIS package would be stored as a .dtsx file, or perhaps in the MSDB database. Either way, you should be able to locate it, open it in a copy of BIDS that you run as the user that executes the application, configure BIDS to have the same set of conditions as how you call the package, and then debug it from there.